# How to merge some parts of the image into one with FFmpeg?

Tags: c, ffmpeg

It is possible to merge some parts of the image to one combined output image in the FFMPEG C library.

Like Java Graphics `Graphics.drawImage (Image, x, y, null);`

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.
FFMEG has an interface which retrieves "frames". You can then access the frames as an in-memory pixel buffer, and process as you want, including combining one frame with a previous one, or taking frames from two video sources and building a combined image where one source is a window in the other.
But FFMEG won't do that for you.

Here's the bit of the example code where you read the frame.
https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.1/demuxing_decoding_8c-example.html

```
if (pkt.stream_index == video_stream_idx) {
        /* decode video frame */
        ret = avcodec_decode_video2(video_dec_ctx, frame, got_frame, &pkt);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error decoding video frame (%s)\n", av_err2str(ret));
            return ret;
        }
        if (*got_frame) {
            if (frame->width != width || frame->height != height ||
                frame->format != pix_fmt) {
                /* To handle this change, one could call av_image_alloc again and
                 * decode the following frames into another rawvideo file. */
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: Width, height and pixel format have to be "
                        "constant in a rawvideo file, but the width, height or "
                        "pixel format of the input video changed:\n"
                        "old: width = %d, height = %d, format = %s\n"
                        "new: width = %d, height = %d, format = %s\n",
                        width, height, av_get_pix_fmt_name(pix_fmt),
                        frame->width, frame->height,
                        av_get_pix_fmt_name(frame->format));
                return -1;
            }
            printf("video_frame%s n:%d coded_n:%d pts:%s\n",
                   cached ? "(cached)" : "",
                   video_frame_count++, frame->coded_picture_number,
                   av_ts2timestr(frame->pts, &video_dec_ctx->time_base));
            /* copy decoded frame to destination buffer:
             * this is required since rawvideo expects non aligned data */
            av_image_copy(video_dst_data, video_dst_linesize,
                          (const uint8_t **)(frame->data), frame->linesize,
                          pix_fmt, width, height);
            /* write to rawvideo file */
            fwrite(video_dst_data[0], 1, video_dst_bufsize, video_dst_file);
        }
    }
```

Replace the fwrite call with your manipulation of the buffer. Try swapping
red and green as a first test to see that you can manipulate that buffer in any way you want and get confidence.

Comment: Any alternative??

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to use something other than FFMEG just because it won't do frame post-processing for you. Writing a function to paste one rgb buffer into another is orders of magnitude easier than writing FFMEG.